# SQLITE STATEMENT- DATE

Tags: sqlite

I am looking for the SQLite Statement to query just the "YEAR" in a date. The Database I am working from consists of data related to Car Accidents on particular dates. The Accidents that occured are stored in date format YYYY-MM-DD. I am looking to just query the accidents in a year ie 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', '2019-12-31');
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9eecb7/4626)

Answer (score 0):

There is no date data type in sqlite.

From https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> 2.2. Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
>   REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic
>   Gregorian calendar.
>       INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.